# MySQL: date value in table different than value in select result due to timezone

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm running a java based application accessing MySQL with JDBC connector.

If I run this select in MySQL Workbench (where the type of `per_date_from` is `DATE`):

```
select per_date_from from formulas;
```

I get a single row:

```
1993-05-27
```

Now, if I run this Java code:

```
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select per_date_from from formulas");
    while (rs.next()) {
        java.sql.Date d = rs.getDate(1);
        System.out.println("d=" + d);
        java.sql.Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(1);
        System.out.println("ts=" + ts);
    }
```

I get this result in the console:

```
09:35:51,412 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) d=1993-05-26

09:35:51,412 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) ts=1993-05-26 23:00:00.0
```

Both the Java code and the MySQL Workbench have the following option in the connection:

```
serverTimezone=America/New_York
```

What is going on? Why does the column type `DATE` have a time?

**UPDATE**

MySQL server version: 5.7.20

JDBC connector version: 8.0.13

According to [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html) they are compatible

Comment: Have your Java code display the value returned by `java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault().getId()` and then [edit] your question to show us what it is.

Comment: It prints `GMT-05:00`, which is correct. Anyway, after a few updates the problem disappeared. Maybe something got wrong when I traveled, my machine was `GMT-06:00` and the connection was `GMT-05:00` when I generated the data. In any case, I shouldn't see different results in Workbench and JDBC. Any ideas what could have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas what could have happened?

Daylight Saving Time. `serverTimezone=America/New_York` tells MySQL Connector/J to use that time zone, which observes DST. However, your JVM is using `GMT-05:00` which is a fixed offset and does not observe DST. So if the MySQL DATE happens to be during the period where New York is on Eastern Daylight Time then the `Timestamp` will be an hour off ...

```java
sql = "SELECT CAST('1993-05-27' AS DATE)"; 
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
rs.next();
Timestamp t = rs.getTimestamp(1);
System.out.println(t);  // 1993-05-26 23:00:00.0
```

... whereas if the date was during the period when New York was on Eastern Standard Time then the `Timestamp` would contain the correct date:

```java
sql = "SELECT CAST('1993-01-27' AS DATE)"; 
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
rs.next();
Timestamp t = rs.getTimestamp(1);
System.out.println(t);  // 1993-01-27 00:00:00.0
```

Moral of the story:

Stop using `java.sql.Timestamp`. For column types like DATE and DATETIME that do not contain timezone information use `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead.

Comment: But how do you explain that the same select statement returned different results in MySQL Workbench and JDBC, even when using `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL Workbench is using JDBC? I haven't used Workbench in a long time, but I don't remember it using JDBC drivers or ODBC drivers or anything like that; AFAIK it just uses its built-in native MySQL access layer for the platform on which it is running.

Comment: MySQL Workbench doesn't use JDBC, but the connection was set with `serverTimezone=America/New_York` same as the JDBC example.  They're results were different and I don't understand why.

Comment: When you say "the [Workbench] connection was set with `serverTimezone=America/New_York`" are you talking about doing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDmMW.png)? If so, then the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html) makes no mention of setting the server timezone for Connector/C++ (it's a Connector/J thing) and Workbench probably just spits out what's in the column much like Connector/J would do if you used `java.time.Date` instead of the old, deprecated, and flaky `java.sql.Date/Timestamp`.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about that configuration. go it, thanks.